# From where geocode server Apple API get its information

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-location

I'm working on backend of my iOS app. 
I need a list of all countries that CoreLocation might return. i.e If I was in U.S the returned county will be U.S or United State. 
I searched and find that CoreLocation used  geocode API:
[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW4)
but I didn't find from where it gets its information.
Anyone knows form where I can get this information?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve? Even if you find out from where Apple gets it's data you will probably won't have access to that. So let us know what are you trying to achieve and we might know a workaround

Comment: hey 
i only need to know if geo location gets its information form mapkit or from other place. 
because in my api, the name of country is important,  for example if core location return the country U.S and in my api i was put United State there will be a problem :S
so that's why i need to know the form of country name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLPlacemark` has a [`ISOcountryCode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLPlacemark/ISOcountryCode) property which returns the country code conforming to the [ISO 3166-1 alpha 2 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1).